# Connection String Properties has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have following method which uses the query but visual studio throws the error as shown in the diagram.

```
private void FindOrderData()
        {
            int intOrder = int.Parse(frmInput.InvoiceOrder);

            string InvSql = "SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.Freight," +
                "Customers.CompanyName, Customers.City, " +
                "(Employees.FirstName + Space(1) + Employees.LastName) As Salesperson " +
                "FROM ((Orders " +
                "INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID) " +
                "INNER JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID) " +
                "WHERE Orders.OrderID = " + "10655";

            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
            OleDbCommand cmdOrder = new OleDbCommand(InvSql, cnn);
            cnn.Open();

            OleDbDataReader rdrOrder = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader();

            // Get CompanyName, City, Salesperson, OrderID, OrderDate and Freight
            rdrOrder.Read();
            CustomerName = rdrOrder["CompanyName"].ToString();
            CustomerCity = rdrOrder["City"].ToString();
            SellerName = rdrOrder["Salesperson"].ToString();
            SaleID = rdrOrder["OrderID"].ToString();
            System.DateTime dtOrder = Convert.ToDateTime(rdrOrder["OrderDate"]);
            SaleDate = dtOrder.ToShortDateString();
            SaleFreight = Convert.ToDecimal(rdrOrder["Freight"]);
            // Get invoice total
            GetInvoiceTotal();

            rdrOrder.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

[image]

```
string strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Northwind.mdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Comment: what does the strCon variable contain?

Comment: Where's `strCon` coming from? I bet you it's null or empty :)

Comment: string strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Northwind.mdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";

Comment: @AmritSharma, where do you call that line?

Comment: I think I was calling it from the class which was not accessible. It worked now thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign `strCon` to the proper connection string. The value of this variable is most likely `null` or `empty`.

For instance:

```
strCon = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;";
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
```

You can find the connection string you need at:

http://connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you copied this code from somewhere else then you missed the line where `strCon` was defined. It should be something like...

```
string strCon = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please stop speculating on this like MVPs.....,

I could reproduce with a strong point, If there is an exception occurred, if you have rolled back your transaction, and try to continue the further data retrieval, Connection is Closed, so the error.

if you want more details about your bug, In VS IDE, keep exception ON. ( Debug --> Exceptions, check on exceptions... )you would see the dirty code which causing this error !

Hydtechie

Comment: HydPhani, speculating ? Your answer is less than that. Why would one disable debug exceptions in the first place ? Yeah, developers writing utter quality applications may have reason to disable them since they might get "bothered" by so many exception dialogs during debugging session.